# How to put .ogg video behind .png image with HTML5 and CSS3?

Tags: html, css, ogg

Everything I try, including z-index (using position:absolute; also), is not working. I want a .png image to go over top of a video, with the video behind also visible through transparent parts of .png file.

Comment: I'd suggest looking into using canvas with video:

http://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/HTML-canvas-guide/PuttingVideoonCanvas/PuttingVideoonCanvas.html

Answer (score 0):

There you go: http://jsfiddle.net/MZm4b/